# How add noise to numpy array for random numbers within for loop of seperate function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Running a function within for loop to generate noise around y values in a pd series, isn't accepting the positional value of Y.

I'm running an old script that use to work on python 2, where it produces a random data series with noise added around the y values. Unfortunately it's kicking back saying that the val Is missing as a positional argument in the noise() def. But I think noise() should be accepting the y_i values in the for loop at bottom of the generate_random_dataset function.

```
def noise(yval):

    np.random.seed(0)
    return 0.2*np.asarray(yval)*np.random.normal(size=len(yval))

# Generate a random dataset
def generate_random_dataset(size_of_array=1000, random_state=0):

    np.random.seed(random_state)
    y = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, size_of_array)
    x = range(0, size_of_array)
    y_new = [y_i + index**((size_of_array - index)/size_of_array) + noise()
     for index, y_i in zip(count(), y)]
    return x, pd.Series(y_new)

x1, y1 = generate_random_dataset()

plot_results(x1, y1, window_size=12, #title_for_plot="Statinoary Standard  Deviation",
                sigma_value=2, text_xlabel="Time in Days", text_ylabel="Value in $")
```

Error I'm getting:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-4b3c87d758ca> in <module>()
 23     return x, pd.Series(y_new)
 24 
---> 25 x1, y1 = generate_random_dataset()
 26 
 27 plot_results(x1, y1, window_size=12, #title_for_plot="Statinoary     Standard Deviation",

<ipython-input-92-4b3c87d758ca> in generate_random_dataset(size_of_array, random_state)
 20     x = range(0, size_of_array)
 21     y_new = [y_i + index**((size_of_array - index)/size_of_array) + noise()
---> 22      for index, y_i in zip(count(), y)]
 23     return x, pd.Series(y_new)
 24 

<ipython-input-92-4b3c87d758ca> in <listcomp>(.0)
 20     x = range(0, size_of_array)
 21     y_new = [y_i + index**((size_of_array - index)/size_of_array) + noise()
---> 22      for index, y_i in zip(count(), y)]
 23     return x, pd.Series(y_new)
 24 

 TypeError: noise() missing 1 required positional argument: 'yval'
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for the `count`function?

Comment: You are forgetting to pass the parameter `yval` to the function `noise()`.

Comment: Do you mean within the + noise() ?

Comment: I tried this:` 
    y_new = [y_i + index**((size_of_array - index)/size_of_array) + noise(y_i)
     for index, y_i in zip(count(), y)]
    return x, pd.Series(y_new)`
  **but it tells me that "TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()"**

Comment: I'm just getting count from itertools